# Why my operators <= are converted in &lt;?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm in Appearance --> Theme Option, where I put my JavaScript code, so I do this:

```
 if(price<=LIMITLESS){
        console.log("home 1");

    }else{
         console.log("Home2");
    }
```

So when I load the web site, I read the console and I read this error:

> Unexpected token ;

and when I click the line where the exception is thrown

```
if(price&lt;LIMITLESS)
```

Anyone can help me to avoid this error?

Comment: Did you wrap them inside `<script>` tags?

Comment: Yes, wordpress put into <script> tags?

Comment: Wait. If it was a text area, you have to use the **Text** and not **Visual** and put them into script tags. I am trying to find an example. While, can you please add a screenshot of how it looks when you add the script inside your WordPress window, please?

Comment: You have not included enough details.  Not all themes have the `Appearance=>Theme Option` setting.  Which theme are you using?

Comment: As a side-note, I'd _strongly_ encourage you to write your scripts into a simple plugin rather than in "Theme Options" of a theme....